# VS 2013 - SonarQube Integration error during build

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am getting the following error when I queue my build in VS 2013.

> File not found: C:\sonarqube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe

The file does exist in the folder. I have mentioned this path in the pre-build script path of the build definition. Screenshots are attached below.

> SoarQube version - 5.6.6

Looking for a solution and I would appreciate all you help!

Comment: Screenshots:                                             
            https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ilcV.jpg 
            https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3PHD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I guess at least one of your build agents does not have this folder, or the build user does not have proper access to it.

So my suggestion is to double check that *all* of your build agents have this folder:

```
C:\sonarqube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe
```

and *also* that the build user has read/execute access on it.

Comment: Thanks Valeri, I was able to get past this error.    Now I am facing another error and would appreciate your help on this as well    The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
      01:26:11.33  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1